# Does this official "Enforce MFA" AWS policy make any sense?

Tags: authentication, multi-factor, aws, amazon

At https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/mfa-iam-user-aws-cli/ the AWS officially recommends to have this policy

```
{

            "Sid": "BlockMostAccessUnlessSignedInWithMFA",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "NotAction": [
                "iam:CreateVirtualMFADevice",
                "iam:DeleteVirtualMFADevice",
                "iam:ListVirtualMFADevices",
                "iam:EnableMFADevice",
                "iam:ResyncMFADevice",
                "iam:ListAccountAliases",
                "iam:ListUsers",
                "iam:ListSSHPublicKeys",
                "iam:ListAccessKeys",
                "iam:ListServiceSpecificCredentials",
                "iam:ListMFADevices",
                "iam:GetAccountSummary",
                "sts:GetSessionToken"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "Bool": {
                    "aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": "false"
                }
            }
}
```

which presumably is supposed to enforce MFA requirement for the account.

But to me having `"iam:DeleteVirtualMFADevice"` makes it not very useful.

2FA to me is a second measure to protect authentication flow: you must know not only a password, but also a 2FA device.

Now with this policy - it allows to remove a virtual mfa as long as you have a valid access token.

And `"iam:DeleteVirtualMFADevice"` cannot be removed from there: if one removes it - then the aws console mfa setup page is broken (it says the MFA already exists, even if it wasn't set up yet).

Am I missing something or is it a security theatre happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delete an MFA device, you should first deactivate it. If it is deactivated, you cannot use it for MFA any more. Thus, it makes sense.